# Merge/join longitudinal data based on two variables

Tags: r, join, merge, longitudinal

I am trying to merge two longitudinal data which are both in the long format.

```
df1:
patientid visit mental-health
703-FD    1     depressed
703-FD    2     depressed
703-FD    3     depressed
707-NM    1     non-depressed
707-NM    2     non-depressed
707-NM    3     depressed 

df2:
patientid visit HIV_disclosure 
703-FD    1     yes
703-FD    2     yes
703-FD    3     yes
707-NM    1     no
707-NM    2     no
707-NM    3     yes
```

Code I've tried:

```
data_combined <- full_join(x=df1, y=df2, by="patientid"): 

patientid visit.x mental-health  visit.y   HIV disclosure
703-FD    1       depressed      1         yes
703-FD    1       depressed      2         yes
703-FD    1       depressed      3         yes
703-FD    2       depressed      1         yes
703-FD    2       depressed      2         yes
703-FD    2       depressed      3         yes
703-FD    3       depressed      1         yes
703-FD    3       depressed      2         yes
703-FD    3       depressed      3         yes
707-NM    1     non-depressed    1         no
707-NM    1     non-depressed    2         no
707-NM    1     non-depressed    3         yes
707-NM    2     non-depressed    1         no
707-NM    2     non-depressed    2         no
707-NM    2     non-depressed    3         yes
707-NM    3     depressed        1         no
707-NM    3     depressed        2         no
707-NM    3     depressed        3         yes
```

How do I edit the above code to merge by both the patientid and the visit variable?

I've tried:

```
library (dplyr)
data_combined <- full_join(x=df1, y=df2, by="patientid", "visit")
```

Desired joined/merged dataframe:

```
patientid visit  mental-health  HIV disclosure
703-FD    1       depressed         yes
703-FD    2       depressed         yes
703-FD    3       depressed         yes
707-NM    1     non-depressed       no
707-NM    2     non-depressed       no
707-NM    3       depressed         yes
```

I'm sure it's a simple code, but I've been struggling with it for a while; please assist.

Comment: `data_combined <- full_join(x=df1, y=df2, by=c("patientid", "visit"))`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: Can you post data as strcuture or data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `dplyr` join functions will join by all variables in common. In your data, those two variables are `patientid` and `visit`. So, for the sample data you provide, the following simplified code should work:

```
library(dplyr)
data_combined <- full_join(x=df1, y=df2)
```

If you want to specify the two columns (perhaps there are more columns in common), then you need to provide a vector to the `by =`  argument.

```
data_combined <- full_join(x=df1, y=df2, by = c("patientid", "visit"))
```

Your original code only supplied `by = 'patientid'`. Since `'visit'` was after the comma, `full_join()` would try to apply `'visit'` to another possible argument for `full_join()`.